# Subdivisions capped at 10, need 13 cuts

Tags: modeling, edges

I am slicing up a predefined geometric pattern for floor tiles that I intend to make a normal map from.

I have an edge with an irrational length that cannot be changed and must be cut into 13 (prime) equal sections. The problem is that the subdivision tool is capped at 10 (that is, 11 sections). What is a workaround for this problem? I cannot type in "12", I can only use the arrows on the menu. I use Blender 2.79.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you type in "12" ?

Comment: The program does not allow me to select the numerical portion, I can only increment it using the arrow buttons. I also miscounted for this example, but have the same problem quite often with other cuts I need to make, so a solution is still needed. What release and OS are you using?

Comment: Does it allow you to enter numerical values in other fields of the Subdivide tool (like "Smoothness", "Fractal"...) ? (2.79, Win10 and Kubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Try two subdivisions of 6 and one then extrude the last

Comment: Extrude the edge into a polygon, use loopcuts (Ctrl-R), set 12 with scrollwheel, delete the extruded portion. You are left with segmented edge without the need to edit any input field.

Comment: Thank you, Jaroslav, that suggestion was a suitable workaround for this kind of problem